# Getting Table of Contents(text and hierarchy) from Wikipedia using jsoup

Tags: java, dom, web-scraping, jsoup

Below is a code that I used to get the 'Contents' section of Wikipedia for a particular topic. I need help in getting the hierarchy of the text as well and then add it to a Map. E.g. if we search for coffee we get:

```
1   Etymology
2   History
2.1 Legendary accounts
2.2 Historical transmission
3   Biology
4   Cultivation
4.1 Ecological effects
5   Production
6   Processing
6.1 Roasting
6.2 Grading roasted beans
6.3 Roast characteristics
6.4 Decaffeination
6.5 Storage
```

I want to preserve the hierarchy(4,4.1) i.e. parent node and respective child nodes along with the text and add these as key value pairs in a hashmap. How do  do that using my code?

```
public static void getWikiNodesForTopic(String url) throws IOException {


       Response res = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .execute();

        String html = res.body();
        Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);

        Elements elements = doc.body().select(".toctext");

        for (Element element : elements) {

            if (element.text().contentEquals("See also") || element.text().contentEquals("References") || element.text().contentEquals("Bibliography") || element.text().contentEquals("External links") || element.text().contentEquals("Bibliography"))
                continue;

            else
                //System.out.println(element.select(".tocnumber"));
                System.out.println(element.ownText());
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the table of contents value is a sibling to the text value you want, you can do this:

```
for (Element element : elements) {

    if (element.text().contentEquals("See also") || element.text().contentEquals("References") || element.text().contentEquals("Bibliography") || element.text().contentEquals("External links") || element.text().contentEquals("Bibliography"))
        continue;

    else
        // This will get the element immediately before the current one.
        System.out.print(element.previousElementSibling().text() + " ");
        System.out.println(element.ownText());
}
```